# Where should location information go?

Tags: rest, endpoint

I'm making an app that lets people see local sports club around them. I want to implement a RESTful API.
What should the the REST endpoint look like to find nearby clubs? Where should the latitude/longitude information go?
I was thinking either

```
GET /nearby_clubs/40.7127/74.0059
```

or

```
GET /nearby_clubs?lat=40.7127&lng=74.0059
```

Are either of these any good?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if you want to implement a REST API, your GET /nearby_clubs Method should consume a XML or JSON input, and then produces a response with same format.

If you use GET `/nearby_clubs/40.20/131.12` or `GET /nearby_clubs?lat=40.7127&lng=74.0059` you could never extend your REST API in future without changing your existing API.. Perhaps you would like to GET not only nearby club but nearby XYZ and you could do easyly with

```
GET /nearby/clubs
GET /nearby/XYZ
```

what consumes and produces their own "thing"..

Some good examples:
[Spring REST API](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-xml-android/)

[Jersey Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/xml-example-with-jersey-jaxb/)